Android SurfaceView operation on Video to Pinch/Scale/Zoom/Bg Color
I'm working on a feature in which I need to perform some actions on the selected video from the gallery and then upload it on the Backend server, I'm mentioning a few of the video editing features on which I'm stuck now:

I had to use the SurfaceView, as in the project it's being required by a 3rd party SDK which requires the SurfaceView's instance and handling a few edits on the Video/Image.
I can pinch it to scale up/down, move the video on the whole screen, and place it anywhere, just like the Instagram app.
I can apply a background color which will be applied to the whole space of the outer of the video frame.
After all the above changes I want an output video that will contain all the changes that I've mentioned above.

I've tried a few solutions with the TextureView and it's working on it, but not with the SurfaceView.
Below is the solution that is working with the TextureView:
class VideoEditActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var textureView: TextureView
    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer
    private lateinit var videoContainer: FrameLayout
    private var scaleGestureDetector: ScaleGestureDetector? = null
    private var gestureDetector: GestureDetector? = null
    private var scaleFactor = 1.0f
    private var translationX = 0f
    private var translationY = 0f
    private var rotationDegrees = 0f
    private var initialRotationDegrees = 0f
    private lateinit var selectedFilePath: String

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_edit)

        textureView = findViewById(R.id.textureView)
        videoContainer = findViewById(R.id.videoContainer)
        videoContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.color.purple_200)
        selectedFilePath = getPathFromUri(Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_DATA)))
        Logger.log("Selected file path: $selectedFilePath")
        findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.ivVideoPlay).setOnClickListener {
//            captureAndCreateVideo()
        }
        setupMediaPlayer()
        setupGestures()
    }

    private fun setupMediaPlayer() {
        textureView.surfaceTextureListener = object : TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {
            override fun onSurfaceTextureAvailable(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {
                val selectedMediaUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_DATA))
                selectedMediaUri?.let {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this@VideoEditActivity, it) // Adjust the source accordingly
                }
                mediaPlayer.setSurface(Surface(surface))
                mediaPlayer.isLooping = true
                mediaPlayer.start()
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(surface: SurfaceTexture, width: Int, height: Int) {}

            override fun onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(surface: SurfaceTexture): Boolean {
                mediaPlayer.release()
                return true
            }

            override fun onSurfaceTextureUpdated(surface: SurfaceTexture) {}
        }
    }

    private fun setupGestures() {
        scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
            override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
                scaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor
                scaleFactor = max(0.1f, min(scaleFactor, 5.0f)) // Limit scaling
                textureView.scaleX = scaleFactor
                textureView.scaleY = scaleFactor
                return true
            }
        })

        gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
                translationX -= distanceX
                translationY -= distanceY
                textureView.translationX = translationX
                textureView.translationY = translationY
                return true
            }
        })

        videoContainer.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            if (event.pointerCount == 2) {
                if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                    initialRotationDegrees = rotation(event)
                } else if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                    val currentRotationDegrees = rotation(event)
                    val deltaDegrees = initialRotationDegrees - currentRotationDegrees
                    rotationDegrees -= deltaDegrees
                    textureView.rotation = rotationDegrees
                    initialRotationDegrees = currentRotationDegrees
                }
            }
            scaleGestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
            gestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
            true
        }
    }

    private fun rotation(event: MotionEvent): Float {
        val dx = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1)).toDouble()
        val dy = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1)).toDouble()
        return Math.toDegrees(atan2(dy, dx)).toFloat()
    }


    private fun getPathFromUri(uri: Uri): String {
        var filePath: String? = null
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
        val cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA)
            filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
            cursor.close()
        }
        return filePath ?: ""
    }
}


XML activity_video_edit file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/ivSelectedImage"
        android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:contentDescription="selected_image" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"> <!-- Background color -->

        <TextureView
            android:id="@+id/textureView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play_icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/ivVideoPlay"/>

</RelativeLayout>

Expected result is: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1459VgzTby7P6prwDGkz2aHClhc2VW206/view?usp=sharing
Update:
I'm able to achieve the pinch/scale up/down with the below solution but the rotation is not working as I was showing in the expected result video (only container is rotating not the content within the SurfaceView):
    private fun setupSurfaceGestures() {
    scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, object : ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener() {
        override fun onScale(detector: ScaleGestureDetector): Boolean {
            scaleFactor *= detector.scaleFactor
            scaleFactor = max(0.1f, min(scaleFactor, 5.0f)) // Limit scaling
            // Update the SurfaceView scale here if possible or handle via custom drawing
            surfaceView.scaleX = scaleFactor
            surfaceView.scaleY = scaleFactor
            return true
        }
    })

    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(this, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
            translationX -= distanceX
            translationY -= distanceY
            // Update the SurfaceView translation here if possible or handle via custom drawing
            surfaceView.translationX = translationX
            surfaceView.translationY = translationY
            return true
        }
    })

    videoContainer.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
        if (event.pointerCount == 2) {
            if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN) {
                initialRotationDegrees = rotation(event)
            } else if (event.actionMasked == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                val currentRotationDegrees = rotation(event)
                val deltaDegrees = initialRotationDegrees - currentRotationDegrees
                rotationDegrees -= deltaDegrees
                surfaceView.rotation = rotationDegrees
                initialRotationDegrees = currentRotationDegrees
            }
        }
        scaleGestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
        gestureDetector?.onTouchEvent(event)
        true
    }

Output video after this change: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hHAfWf_NnplzrRdHYKgjXk-tf8etZRmJ/view?usp=sharing

Stack Overflow is for programming questions. What is your question? Note that if the question is "how do all of the many things that I list here?", your question may be closed for needing more focus.

@CommonsWare I've added the approach and result with the solution that I've tried, it's just if someone in the past has faced the same type of issue. Then it'll be a great help to me

SurfaceView is different from other views in that it doesn't draw anything on its Canvas, and instead it "punches a hole in its window to allow its surface to be displayed". And although it lets you apply certain transformations to the Surface (such as changing position and scale) it doesn't support changing the rotation.
TextureView on the other hand behaves as a regular View. So you can change its rotation and alpha freely.
But if you must use a SurfaceView then any custom transformations must be done manually. For efficiency, you probably want to utilize hardware acceleration. Note that this required writing a large amount of code.
Here's one possible workflow: MediaCodec decodes video frames; SurfaceTexture makes them available to the GPU as an external texture; OpenGL ES renders a textured rectangle while applying a transformation matrix; the Surface of the SurfaceView serves as an EGL window surface; application controls the playback speed according to the video frame rate.
